How to Select a big amount of data in MySQL in less time
I was trying to select a database here, with just about 6M rows, but the database is spending a huge amount of time to fetch it. It's from a on premises server, but should fetch it in less time, could someone help me to build a query that return the same data but in less time?
Here some infos about it.
The Query: 
The Return: 

There is nothing to optimise on a query that selects all columns and all rows in a table. Why do you want to fetch 6 million rows in the first place?

is this a table or a view?  are you connecting on your local network or using a vpn or anything that would be less direct?  do you really need all the rows?  do you really need all the columns (select * is bad practice, you should be explicit about which columns you want)?

what are you doing with these rows after fetching them?

@ysth Exactly. What's the use case? Who will look at 6 million rows? If it's a batch process than it's OK if it takes some time... because I would assume the OP should not be reading 6 million rows for an "online query".

I guess the figures shown by your client are query execution time (47 ms) and network transfer (~8 minutes). Whether it's fast or it's slow depends on how many MB worth of data you have (row count alone won't tell you that). In general terms, what you do with large datasets is to paginate for display and run as background process for bulk processing.

@ysth I'm importing it to Power BI to analyze this data, I need all the columns to analyze, that's why I need a faster query. I'm Using VPN.

@TheImpaler I'm running it using VPN to fetch from a onpremises server, I need all the columns because I'm analysing it on power bi, all the columns on this table are important. That's why I need a faster query.

there isn't going to be a faster query.  if you can ditch the vpn and be directly on the local network, that could help.  or get a faster internet connection.  or work out a way to only need a subset of the data at one time.

I do not know the size of the table, but could easily be in the gigabytes. Tranferring gigabytes of data over vpn in a few minutes is pretty good performance!

@Shadow the size is about 900mb, do you think is a good performance for it?

you could dump the data, transfer the dump file, and load it in a database that's on the network or machine where you are running power bi.

Yeah, I agree with @ysth, implement a data pipeline to get your data from your local database to azure on a regular basis and have powerbi query the azure data source

@Shadow azure? oh, if they are running power bi in the cloud? most people asking about it are using the desktop version, where data in azure wouldn't help

@ysth I was trying to use Index on the database, but it didn't work

@JhonattaSilva an index would only help if you eanted to filter in the query. You want to dump the whole table - no index will help with that. We told you several times that you cannot optimise the query.

@ysth the OP talks about the data being on-prem, so it stands to reason that they use a cloud. Desktop power bi is good for development only, you need the online version if you want to distribute it to different users.

@Shadow sure, that makes sense. the slow transfer speed and transfer over a vpn make me think desktop. but I don't know much about power bi.

900MB in 8 minutes is 15Mbps if I didn't mess maths. What figures do you get if you do a speed test?

To reduce the duration time you need to update the table structure, Like try to normalize a query(add where clause) and reduce the number of columns(select required columns only).
And you are not using any joins in the query so it is a good thing.
Add indexing to your table.
Check Query Execution Plan in the editor.
To improve the performance, Update your system configuration like processor RAM and memory is also important.

@JhonattaSilva Your query time is less than 1/20th of a second. As repeatedly pointed out in the comments, it's the transfer of the result data that is taking a long time. As such, none of the suggestions made in this "answer" would do anything to solve your problem. Could you clarify why you chose to accept this answer?
